# Laravel Polymorph Attachement

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, attachment, polymorphic-associations

So im figuring out how to construct an attachable object with the laravel framework, since they implement polymorphic relationships.

My scenario is the following: I have one Object, which we will call the Attachable-Object. You can attach different kind of objects to it, which we will call the Attachement-Object. So for example you have an image saved and want to attach this to different advertisements, profiles, blogposts etc.

So in theory there should be a table with the following structure:

```
 id | attachable_id | attachable_type | attachment_id | attachable_type | ...
 1  |             1 |   advertisement |             1 |           image | ...
 1  |             2 |         profile |             1 |           image | ...
 1  |             1 |   advertisement |             3 |           video | ...
```

This structure is very extendable, since you dont need to add extra columns in other tables or create tables for many-to-many relations.

***First Question***: Is this structure a good idea, if you want to add attachements to an Object which type you dont know?

Currently I am wondering, how to implement this with the polymorphic relationship from the laravel framework. I know it is possible to use it for a one-to-one or many-to-many polymorphic relationship. But all I can find about it are scenarios which taggable or comments, where you exactly specify the attachable object.

***Second Question***: How to implement this in the laravel way with polymorphic relationships? Is it even possible?

I guess there should be an Attachment-Model, which will implement both ways like this:

```
// Attachment Class
...
public function attachable(){
    return $this->morphTo();
}
public function attachment(){
    return $this->morphTo();
}
...


// Advertisement Class
...
public function attachement(){
    return $this->morphOne('App\Attachment', 'attachment');
}
...

// Image Class
...
public function attachable(){
    return $this->morphOne('App\Attachment', 'attachable');
}
...
```

But what is the right way to do it? Hope somebody implemented something similar and can help me with this.

Comment: Have you seen the example in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)? I think it's just what you need

Comment: Yeah ive seen it and it would work, if i would use the attachement table, where the attachable object (advertisement etc) is defined. I just leave this idea here, and will implement it like in the documentation. For this i will create an AdvertisementAttachment table, which wil implement the polymorphic relation. For more Attachments i will have to create a second ***Attachment table.